# getting "cannot assign null value to int type" error on linq to sql left join

Tags: c#, linq

Here is the code:

```
var kids = (from relations in masterDB.mrrel_Limited2s
                        join conso in masterDB.mrconso_Limiteds on relations.AUI2 equals conso.AUI
                        join a in masterDB.tbl_patients_problems_problemId_to_SnoMed_Iteration2_before_doc_final_s on conso.SCUI equals a.SnoMedScui into aGroup
                        where relations.AUI1.Equals(contextDictionary["CategoryID"].ToString())
                        &&
                        relations.REL.Equals("CHD")
                        from aa in aGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new
                        {
                            aui2 = relations.AUI2,
                            name = conso.STR,
                            problemId = aa.ProblemId
                        }).ToList();
```

This line throws the error. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `aGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()` will give `null` when no records match, you need to check that while using. While assigning the value to problemId, check for null. 
Try this:-

```
from aa in aGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
           select new
           {
               aui2 = relations.AUI2,
               name = conso.STR,
               problemId = aa != null ? aa.ProblemId : 0
           }).ToList();
```